# [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023024] No data to upload. Upload task will not be scheduled

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-analytics

- I integrated FireBase Analytics in a project SDK Cocoa Touch Framework
- I Integrate without CocoaPods
- In my project demo I Call function:[SDKManager handleApplication:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions]; for init [FIRApp configure] in my SDK

  (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  ```
  [FIRApp configure];
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  //[SDKManager defaultManager].isSandbox = true;
  [SDKManager handleApplication:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  ```

In My SDK create this func:

```
+ (void)handleApplication:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[SDKManager defaultManager] handleApplication:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    [VTCSDKAppDelegate loadSDKAppDelegate];
    [[SDKManager defaultManager] initSDK];
}

- (void)handleApplication:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // hide the status bar
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleApplicationWillEnterBackground:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleApplicationWillEnterForeground:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleApplicationWillTerminate:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleApplicationDidBecomeActive:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];

    // Facebook
    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

    //FireBase
    [FIRApp configure];
}
```

But ***but checking no data on Console FireBase***

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sVBw.png)

Comment: I could see some exceptions in the log. Did you just download the Zip file and added it into your project?

Comment: yes, I Added it to my project, I download from https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup?authuser=0

Comment: I can see Log in https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sVBw.png

Comment: Can you create an empty project and try to add Firebase Analytics SDK similarly and let us know whether this problem still persists? Please make sure to follow the README in the zip file closely. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. fireBase feedback is don't support Dynamic framework, thank all